# in C# Console Application, how to Block Full Screen?

Tags: c#, console-application, screen, fullscreen

in C# Console Application, how to Block Full Screen?

I want to block the possibility of resizing or moving the console window after it is putting in full screen.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    #region Dll Import
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
    #endregion

    static void Main()
    {
        //int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;
        IntPtr hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
        if(hWnd != IntPtr.Zero) ShowWindow(hWnd, 3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Blocking the possibility of resizing or moving the console window isn't directly supported through the Windows Console API. The console window's behavior is controlled by the Windows operating system.

If you want to create a custom UI that behaves like a console window but doesn't allow resizing or moving, you may consider creating a Windows Forms or WPF application instead of a pure console application.